Deciding between raidz1, raidz2 and mdraid6 for JBOD Array
Have a new Linux server with a dual SAS attached 60 bay JBOD filled with 20TB (18.2 TiB) disks.  I am definitely running ZFS but trying to figure out whether to use small raidz1's, bigger raidz2, or mdadm based RAID6.
So I created all three and ran some tests.
zpool create tank1 raidz2 /dev/mapper/JBODSLOT0{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} /dev/mapper/JBODSLOT1{0,1}

zpool create tank2 raidz /dev/mapper/JBODSLOT1{2,3,4,5,6,7} raidz /dev/mapper/JBODSLOT1{8,9} /dev/mapper/JBODSLOT2{0,1,2,3}

mdadm --level=6 --raid-devices=12 /dev/mapper/JBODSLOT4{8,9} /dev/mapper/JBODSLOT5{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
zpool create vault1 /dev/md127

First disadvantage of the md raid6 is having to wait 36 hours for the initial sync to finish before running performance tests.
The big difference is amount of usable space each gives:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
vault1          182T   65G  182T   1% /vault1
tank2           175T   48G  175T   1% /tank2
tank1           167T   54G  167T   1% /tank1

with the md raid6 being the big winner here.  The amount of lost capacity on the raidz2 setup seems crazy.
I then ran various performance tests using "fio" knowing that with all the caches and buffering involved I would not get anything definitive.  And that pretty much was the case with read (both serial and random) being crazy scattered.  The write tests were a bit more consistent with:
md raid6  WRITE: bw=129MiB/s (136MB/s), 16.1MiB/s-16.3MiB/s (16.9MB/s-17.1MB/s), io=15.2GiB (16.3GB), run=120053-120053msec
raidz2    WRITE: bw=165MiB/s (173MB/s), 20.6MiB/s-20.7MiB/s (21.6MB/s-21.7MB/s), io=19.3GiB (20.8GB), run=120020-120020msec
2xraidz1  WRITE: bw=176MiB/s (184MB/s), 21.9MiB/s-22.1MiB/s (22.0MB/s-23.1MB/s), io=20.6GiB (22.1GB), run=120001-120001msec

I then rebooted the server to clear everything and then did some simple dd tests on the big files that fio had created on each volume
[root@lcnsrv03 ~]# cd /tank1/fiotest/
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# dd if=fiotest.2.0 bs=128K skip=20000 count=100000 of=/dev/null
45536+0 records in
45536+0 records out
5968494592 bytes (6.0 GB, 5.6 GiB) copied, 47.6812 s, 125 MB/s
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# pwd
/tank1/fiotest
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# cd /tank2/fiotest/
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# dd if=fiotest.2.0 bs=128K skip=20000 count=100000 of=/dev/null
45536+0 records in
45536+0 records out
5968494592 bytes (6.0 GB, 5.6 GiB) copied, 28.2565 s, 211 MB/s
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# cd /vault1/fiotest/
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# dd if=fiotest.2.0 bs=128K skip=20000 count=100000 of=/dev/null
45536+0 records in
45536+0 records out
5968494592 bytes (6.0 GB, 5.6 GiB) copied, 26.2081 s, 228 MB/s
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# cd /tank1/fiotest/
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# dd if=fiotest.3.0 bs=128K skip=20000 count=100000 of=/dev/null
45536+0 records in
45536+0 records out
5968494592 bytes (6.0 GB, 5.6 GiB) copied, 47.3928 s, 126 MB/s
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# cd /tank2/fiotest/
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# dd if=fiotest.3.0 bs=128K skip=20000 count=100000 of=/dev/null
45536+0 records in
45536+0 records out
5968494592 bytes (6.0 GB, 5.6 GiB) copied, 28.0627 s, 213 MB/s
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# cd /vault1/fiotest/
[root@lcnsrv03 fiotest]# dd if=fiotest.3.0 bs=128K skip=20000 count=100000 of=/dev/null
45536+0 records in
45536+0 records out
5968494592 bytes (6.0 GB, 5.6 GiB) copied, 27.0244 s, 221 MB/s

The poor performance on the raidz2 here is surprising.
"Real world" writing tests using some multi-GB rsync tests show the two zraid pools about 50% faster than the md raid6 pool.  But hard to know when the server has 130GB RAM and cache/buffering is involved.  And after doing
# cat /sys/block/md127/md/stripe_cache_size
256
# echo 32768 > /sys/block/md127/md/stripe_cache_size

the md raid6 rsync write tests are faster than the two raidz ones.
The same rsync tests doing reading seem to confirm the same speed comparison as the 'dd' tests above.
So overall in performance is seems mostly a wash though if anything seems better it is the the md raid6.
After much web searching the only clear advantage I can find with the raidz config over the ZFS on top of md raid6 is the CopyOnWrite to avoid corruption on power outage/crash.  Too bad mdadm bitmaps don't support ZFS.
Am I missing some other big advantage to raidz?  With ZFS on top of md raid6 I still get all the normal ZFS advantages (checksum/compression/encryption/snapshots/resize/quota/...)
So mainly due to the capacity issue I am leaning towards md raid6.

for simple benchmarking, you can skip sync with --assume-clean. in the long run you should still sync, or follow it up with --action=repair, before any drive fails. Since restoring from parity will only work if parity is actually correct...

I did not test, but in theory, ZFS built in raid modes should keep checksums per drive, so if there is any issue with data on any drive, ZFS should still be able to recover it from parity. With md raid, since ZFS won't know about md parity, it could only tell you that data is wrong and not attempt to recover it. That said I currently still use md (and ZFS not at all) but this is personal preference.

There should also be some differences when it comes to growing/reshaping a raid. In the end its quite difficult to compare...
